# Bug in Hello World Objective-C and Xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4.2

I'm new to programming in Objective-C, though I do have some experience in Python. I wrote this (what I thought would be simple) program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I click run in Xcode it gives me this error:

> Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I don't know what I did wrong and was hoping someone could help. It executes from the command line but not from Xcode.

Comment: Can you build other projects?  There should be an error of some kind somewhere....

Comment: are you aware, that this doesn't contain a single Objective-C specific line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other commenters here, I can't see any direct problem with your code, so maybe you could get it to work if you start from a clean project template.

In Xcode, choose New Project, type Command line tool

You can select either straight C or Objective-C. The latter will give you an autorelease pool that you don't need for a Hello World program, but it doesn't harm, either.

Then type your code (printf("Your text\n")) into the main function and compile.

It should work.